# Javascript Prototyping Question

Tags: javascript

I'm just reading about Prototypes in JavaScript and Douglas Crockford offers and excellent way to select a new objects prototype but can anyone explain (below) why obj01's type equals 'object' when I pass it in function as it's prototype?

```
if (typeof Object.beget !== 'function') {
     Object.beget = function (o) {
         console.log(typeof o);//function
         var F = function () {};
         F.prototype = o;
         console.log(typeof F);//function
         return new F();
     };
}
var func01 = function(){};
var obj01 = Object.beget(func01);
console.log(typeof obj01);//object
console.log(typeof obj01.prototype);//object
```

I thought it would be

```
console.log(typeof obj01);//function
console.log(typeof obj01.prototype);//function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj01` is simply an object that inherits from a function object, you can't create functions in this way.

The [`typeof`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.4.3) operator returns `"function"` only when its operand is by itself *callable*.

There are only three valid ways to create function objects:

Function declaration:

```
function name (/*arg, argn...*/) {
}
```

Function expression:

```
var fn = function /*nameopt*/ (/*arg, argn...*/) {
};
```

Function constructor:

```
var fn = new Function("arg", "argn", "FunctionBody");
```

**Edit:**  In response to your comment, `obj01` , is just an object, its prototype chain contains a function object, then `Function.prototype` and then `Object.prototype` but that doesn't make an object *callable*.

Your object *is not* callable, functions are just objects, but they have some *special* internal properties that allow them to behave like that.

**An object is callable *only if* it implements the internal [`[[Call]]`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.2) property**.

There are other internal properties that function objects have, like the [`[[Construct]]`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.2), which is invoked when the [`new`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.2) operator is used, the [`[[Scope]]`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.2) property which stores the lexical environment where the function is executed, and more.

If you try to invoke your object like if it were a function, you will have a `TypeError`, because when you make a [function call](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.3), the object needs to have the `[[Call]]` internal property.

Function objects need to have the above internal properties, and *the only way* that they can be constructed is by the three methods I mentioned early, you can see how internally functions objects are created [here](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2).

Comment: Hi CMS, it wasn't that I was trying to create a function. I was trying to understand inheritance and prototyping in JavaScript. 

So if my new object's prototype is now a Function.prototype why isn't my new object callable? Are the call and apply methods not part of the function's prototype that my new object has inherited?

Comment: @Nick: Edited to clarify, please ask if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thanks CMS. That was a very thorough answer. I really appreciate your help. I do have one more question. When you talk about an object's prototype chain, is that stored in it's hidden internal prototype property? I know functions have two prototype properties, one hidden and one not.

Comment: @Nick, exactly, every object has an internal `[[Prototype]]` property, this property is the link between objects that builds up the *prototype chain*, functions have also a `prototype` property, the object referenced by this property will be used as the `[[Prototype]]` of every new object created by the function when it is used as a [constructor](http://bit.ly/cTF1JR), this is done by the `new` operator with the help of the `[[Construct]]` internal operation.

Comment: Thank you so much CMS. I'm really starting to understand how JavaScript works.

Answer (score 1):

Its really quite simple.

The variable `F` points to a function, so `typeof F` returns 'function'.

But the return value from `F()` is an object, an execution context (activation object), or an instance of a class if you want. For more info on this read [this excellent blog series](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-0-introduction/).

Therefor `typeof F()` returns 'object'.

As Martyn showed in his comment; change `return new F();` into `return F;`. That should return  a new function with a modified scope chain usable for instantiating a new 'subclass'.

Comment: @Martyn, that misses completely the point of this `beget` function, create an object that inherits from another...

Comment: @Sean, the value of `new F();` is simply an object (created by the [[[`Construct`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2.2)]] internal operation), it has nothing to do with the activation object, which in this case for `beget` and `F` will be garbage collected after every invocation.

Comment: Its not discarded as long as `new` is used, and the function does not explicitly call `return foo;` Of course, it might be that I'm remembering incorrectly and it wasn't the AO but one of the others.

Comment: @CMS - yup, I missed the nuances of that question. Apologies for any confusion and thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @CMS, Sean, I'm a little confused. Are you saying that when I invoke a Function constructor the object created is not a function?

Comment: @Nick, that is correct. That is unless it uses `return foo;//foo is a function`, but in that case then `new` isn't really needed.